# Multiple Random Variables - Who Wins

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

For $(a)$ I have figured out that I am looking for the value $P(A<B<C)$. I have done this problem with only two turtles, and I have found that the value is the double integral of the two exponential p.d.fs, and that works out to be $\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}$. $\lambda$ and $\mu$ being the means of the turtles. However, I'm not sure what to do for three turtles. I would assume to me that you would just add the third mean to the denominator of the fraction, but I am not certain that such a solution is correct.

For part $(b)$, it seems to be a similar approach, the appropriate mean put in the numerator.

Part $(c)$ and $(d)$ have me confused, because I am not sure I should calculate the expected value of each (which I have) and multiply each by the respective probability of winning or some other way.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

No, for (a) you are looking for the probability that $A < B$ and $A < C$.   You don't care who comes second.

Hint:  These exponential random variables could be the first arrival times for independent Poisson processes with rates $r_A$, $r_B$, $r_C$; the rates are the reciprocals of the mean arrival times.  This could be realized using a single Poisson process of rate $r_A + r_B + r_C$, where each arrival is put in the $A$, $B$ or $C$ process with probabilities proportional to the rates of each.

Comment: Not sure the invocation of some properties of independent Poisson processes will help the OP the least.